# Is there a best practice available for using tags in Cucumber and Gherkin?

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

Is there a best practice available for using tags in Cucumber and Gherkin?

Answer (score 1):

Tags are designed to change the runtime conditions of a scenario. The most used tag is @javascript which (in the ruby world) changes the runtime setup, so that the scenario is run under conditions in which javascript will work properly.

Another classic tag is @wip, which basically says, this is the scenario I am currently working on. This allows us to tell cucumber to only run the scenario we are working on.

My advice would be to not use tags for use cases outside of this, in particular do not use tags to:

1. Do setup for particular scenarios - use a Given instead
2. Group your features by some part of your domain - use the folder structure of your features instead.

In general use tags minimally. Some tags that I have created/used

`@selenium` - tell cucumber to run this particular scenario with a particular setup that will open an actual browser. I use this alot with @wip so I can see what my scenario is doing

`@slow` - tell cucumber that this particular scenario has a high runtime cost. This allows us to not run it every time

Answer (score 0):

I would say common sense is your best friend when using these kind of capabilities of a framework...

IMO the main reasons you want to use tagging is:

1:. Group your features per capability which can come very handy when dealing with a lot of feature files

2:. Reduce complexity of calls you need to perform before or after a set of scenarios that belong to a capability/feature tag (for example data setup/teardown)

If you are not using it with the intent to group your tests or to reduce complexity of your test suite, then you might be doing it wrong.

Also, using tag system to fire your tests within cucumber allows you to play around with cucumber folder structure with no side effects...

if you don't use cucumbers folder structure and don't use tag, then cucumber won't know how to find your tests and you will have to manually state where to find them or recursively require all relevant folders for your features to work

Answer (score 0):

1. Tags are a way to group Scenarios. They are @-prefixed strings and you can place as many tags as you like above Feature, Scenario, Scenario Outline or Examples keywords. Space character are invalid in tags and may separate them.
2. Tags are inherited from parent elements. For example, if you place a tag above a Feature, all scenarios in that feature will get that tag.
3. Similarly, if you place a tag above a Scenario Outline or Examples keyword, all scenarios derived from examples rows will inherit the tags.
4. You can tell Cucumber to only run scenarios with certain tags, or to exclude scenarios with certain tags.

Reference: https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#tags